# Notation for sum of products

Tags: notation, summation

Is there a summation notation for the sum of products made two by two? I have the following expression:

$$x_1x_2+x_1x_3+\dots+x_1x_n+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_2x_5+\dots+x_2x_n+\dots+x_{n-1}x_n$$

Comment: Is this a question about standard mathematical notation or about how to write code in the software system *Mathematica* to represent such a sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are known as the *elementary symmetric polynomials*.

See for instance:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial

$$e_2(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n) \quad = \quad \sum _{1 \leq i < j \leq n} X_i X_j$$

They are also sometimes called the *unitary symmetric functions*.

It is also possible to express your 'conditional' sum $(1 \leq i < j \leq n)$ in terms of simple power sums  $s_r = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^r$. For your problem, the conversion is:

$$e_2(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n) \quad = \quad \sum _{1 \leq i < j \leq n} X_i X_j \quad = \quad  \frac{s_1^2 - s_2}{2} \quad = \quad \frac{ \big(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\big)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}{2} $$

The conversion to power sum notation is automated by the `MonomialToPowerSum` function in the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*. For example, for the 3-product case $\sum _{1 \leq i < j < k \leq n} X_i X_j X_k$:

```
MonomialToPowerSum[{1, 1, 1}, M, s]
```

returns:

$$\frac{s_1^3}{6} - \frac{s_1s_2}{2} + \frac{s_3}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 5;

Sum[x[i] x[j], {i, n}, {j, i + 1, n}]
```

> ```
> x[1] x[2] + x[1] x[3] + x[2] x[3] + x[1] x[4] +
>  x[2] x[4] + x[3] x[4] + x[1] x[5] + x[2] x[5] + x[3] x[5] + x[4] x[5]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on wolfies' answer...Mathematica has the function AugmentedSymmetricPolynomial (among other similar functions).  To get the same answer as above one can use the following:

```
Expand[FullSimplify[
  AugmentedSymmetricPolynomial[{1, 1}, {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]}]/2]]
```

Using this function might be easier for more complicated summations.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like

```
xv = Map[x, Range[1, 5]]
1/2 (Total@Flatten[Outer[Times, xv, xv]] - xv.xv) // Expand
```

which give

```
{x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]}
x[1] x[2] + x[1] x[3] + x[2] x[3] + x[1] x[4] + 
   x[2] x[4] +  x[3] x[4] + x[1] x[5] + x[2] x[5] + x[3] x[5] + x[4] x[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Total[Times @@ Map[Function[y, xx[y]], #] & /@ Subsets[Range[5], {2}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Code golf (not very short, but unintelligible enough)

```
Tr[x@#x@#2&@@@Range@5~Subsets~{2}]

(*
  x[1] x[2] + x[1] x[3] + x[2] x[3] + x[1] x[4] + x[2] x[4] + 
  x[3] x[4] + x[1] x[5] + x[2] x[5] + x[3] x[5] + x[4] x[5]
*)
```

Comment: Doesn't work as written because of the first item in the v9-v10 section [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56729/121).  Add a space and earn a vote. :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yup. [I know](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/38188/315). But that allows me to save one char by golfing in v9 ;D